# Custom inline edit in list view

Tags: listview, sonata-admin

I have a database field which represents the current state of a entity. This field is in the same table as the entity itself.

These states are

```
0 = unchecked
1 = ok
2 = not okay
```

At the moment i represent this field with a choice field

```
->add('status', 'choice', 
array('choices' => ['unverified', 'OK', 'Critical'], 
'editable' => true);
```

For a better workflow, i don't want to render a choice input field, cause its very slow to do 3 clicks to set a state for one entity when having several hundred entities in the list view.

Instead i want to display 2 images as buttons: One button with thumb down representing "not okay", one with thumb up for "ok" and if nothing is checked: unverified. Only one of both or none image can be checked

How can i do this? Has somebody done similar things? Maybe there is a "expanded" option for the choice field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible recipe for your problem

1. Set a custom controller for your admin class and let it extend the CRUDController class.
2. Extend this custom controller class with a method like "updateStatusAction" where your logic for updating the entity status is going here
3. Add a route in the admin class by overriding the configureRoutes method -> add a route matching your updateStatusAction method
4. Set a custom template for your list action. Extend the base_list.html.twig and only override the javascripts block. In general do not change anything but adding your ajax code for handling the clickable elements later.
5. Set a custom template for your desired field in the list action (in your example the "status" field) and place 2 links (or use buttons/images if you like) in it and give them the path to your custom controller method (updateStatusAction) by using the path() method.

Now you have 2 Elements (links/images/buttons) in each row of your list view and when you click on it, the ajax code (defined in your list_view template) will handle the call to your custom controller. Your logic in here will handle the status updating by getting the id and status from your link. It does some entity handling stuff and returns the current status of your entity. You can display this current state for example by colorizing the background of the link you have clicked.

I dont know if this is the best approach, but it's a solution i would consider.